# How to draw a single line using MouseMove Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, graphics, gdi

I'm trying to draw a single line using `OnMouseMove()` event. My Problem is that everytime I move the mouse It leaves a trail. I tried to use the refresh method, but when I stop moving the mouse the line is gone. I don't want the line to be drawn `OnPaint();`, Just want to draw it `OnMouseMove()`.

**EDIT:** I'm using a transparent panel(cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;), so I cant use the `graphics.Clear()` and `BackColor()`

Here's a Sample Image without the `Refresh()`:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  
   Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

   g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   using (var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
   {
      p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
      p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;

      g.DrawLine(p, st, e.Location);
   }
   Thread.Sleep(30);
   Invalidate();
   //this.Refresh();

   g.Dispose();
}
```

Regards

Comment: You can't make this work.  Fix: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3087655c-bd50-4408-9c55-dd179e442675/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me.  Basically keep track of the last line drawn and draw over it with the background color of the panel (gives the effect of clearing it).

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private const int PEN_WIDTH = 3;
      private const LineCap START_CAP = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
      private const LineCap END_CAP = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
      Point mAnchorPoint = new Point(10, 10);
      Point mPreviousPoint = Point.Empty;

      private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
         using (Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics())
         {
            // Clear last line drawn
            using (Pen clear_pen = new Pen(panel1.BackColor, PEN_WIDTH))
            {
               clear_pen.StartCap = START_CAP;
               clear_pen.EndCap = END_CAP;
               g.DrawLine(clear_pen, mAnchorPoint, mPreviousPoint);
            }

            // Update previous point
            mPreviousPoint = e.Location;

            // Draw the new line
            using (Pen draw_pen = new Pen(Color.Black, PEN_WIDTH))
            {
               draw_pen.StartCap = START_CAP;
               draw_pen.EndCap = END_CAP;
               g.DrawLine(draw_pen, mAnchorPoint, e.Location);
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

If you panel's background color is set to Transparent, you will need to change `panel1.BackColor` to `panel1.Parent.BackColor`

If the Transparent Panel is not working, you could use the `DrawReversibleLine` function (although this doesn't allow the color or thickness of the line to be changed, it should have no issues with drawing/erasing even if the panel is Transparent:

```
  Point mAnchorPoint = new Point(200, 200);
  Point mPreviousPoint = Point.Empty;

  private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     if (mPreviousPoint != Point.Empty)
     {
        // Clear last line drawn
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(PointToScreen(mAnchorPoint), PointToScreen(mPreviousPoint), Color.Pink);
     }

     // Update previous point
     mPreviousPoint = e.Location;
     mPreviousPoint.Offset(myPanel1.Location);

     // Draw the new line
     ControlPaint.DrawReversibleLine(PointToScreen(mAnchorPoint), PointToScreen(mPreviousPoint), Color.Pink);
  }
```

Comment: ah yes, this will work fine. But I'm using a transparent panel(CreateParams.ExStyle |= 0x20;).

Comment: I just saw your comments.  You can use `panel1.Parent.BackColor`

Comment: panel1's parent is the form. The transparent panel is flickering to white. when i used `panel1.Parent.BackColor`

Comment: @Rye - Updated my answer with a different approach

Comment: @SwDev Oh! yes the drawreversible line. I forgot. Wait i'll try.

Comment: You save the day @SwDevMan81. I forgot that theres a `DrawReversibleLine()` method. Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to draw a line with mouse in C#:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Options_c o = new Options_c();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        o.Allow = false;

    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        o.Allow = true;
        o.X = e.X;
        o.Y = e.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (o.Allow == true)
        {
            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Pen p1 = new Pen(o.color, 5);
            g.DrawLine(p1, o.X,o.Y, e.X, e.Y);
            o.X = e.X;
            o.Y = e.Y;
        }
    }
}

class Options_c
{
    public Boolean Allow = false;
    public Int32 X;
    public Int32 Y;
    public Color color = Color.Bisque;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: you have to dispose g and pen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the line disappearing is that when the panel is repainted, the line is not redrawn. What you really need is to update the end-point of the line-segment when the mouse is moved across the panel and to *invalidate* the panel. Of course, this will mean that you *do* handle the `Paint` event on the panel.

Code here, without the event-handler registration:

```
Point endPoint;

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    using (var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
    {
        p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
        p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;

        g.DrawLine(p, st, endPoint);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(30);
}

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    endPoint = e.Location;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: the g.Clear() is good. But i forgot to include there that I override a panel user control with CreateParams. So the panel is set to transparent. that's why I cant use the g.Clear();

Comment: @Rye: Alright. But why can't you handle the `Paint` event? That's the easiest way.

Comment: @Rye: Can you explain what that means?

Comment: I have a transparent Panel. It is positioned above an image(e.g picturebox), This image contains line drawings. I just want to measure the drawings using the drawline on `MouseMove()` event.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
g.DrawLine(p, st, e.Location);
```

put:

```
st = e.Location;
```

Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Nope, It just creates new line.

Comment: Oh, right. I thought you were trying to draw like a pencil. I see now that you want to have a single starting place and be able to move the end point around having it redraw only a single line between the start point and the new end point.

Answer (score 0):

> OKaie, i got it! If you have to draw a line between two geopoint
>   location on tocuhing these two location, then u have to use the
>   overlay class in this shape... MY CODE IS :

**in Main activity write this code also:**

```
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView1);            
         mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();//it get the mapview all overlays...

         mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(13);
        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(34159000,73220000);//starting point Abbottabad    
        GeoPoint p1 = new GeoPoint(41159000,43220000);//starting point Abbottabad   
         List<Overlay> mapOverlays2 ;
            mapOverlays2 = mapView.getOverlays();
             projection = mapView.getProjection();  
             myoverlay = new MarkerOverlay(p,p1);
            mapOverlays2.add(myoverlay);//*/

     }


    class MarkerOverlay extends Overlay
    { 
               GeoPoint p,p1;
       private GeoPoint pa;
       public MarkerOverlay(GeoPoint p,GeoPoint p1)
         {  
                     this.p = p;
             this.p1=p1;
            Toast.makeText(GoogleMapShowActivity.this, "point value is "+p +"-->"+p1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }

         public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,boolean shadow)//), long when)
         {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            Paint mPaint = new Paint(); 
         mPaint.setDither(true);    
         mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);    
         mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);  
         mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);    
         mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);  
         mPaint.setStrokeWidth(4); 

         GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(p.getLatitudeE6(),p.getLongitudeE6());//starting point Abbottabad  
         GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(p1.getLatitudeE6(),p1.getLongitudeE6());//(33695043,73050000);//End point Islamabad            


         Point p1 = new Point();    
         Point p2 = new Point();
         Path path1 = new Path();               
         projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);  //changing the latitude into the screen pixels.
         projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);  
        path1.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);//Moving to Abbottabad location
         path1.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);//Path till Islamabad  
      canvas.drawPath(path1, mPaint);//Actually drawing the path from Abbottabad to Islamabad

         }

         //--------------------------//
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
          {
            location_touch++;//this is called two times before executing other codes in thsi method(), 
            // Toast.makeText(GoogleMapShowActivity.this, "this is mmmm"+location_touch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               if (event.getAction() == 1)
               {

                 // Toast.makeText(GoogleMapShowActivity.this, "this is me ..."+location_touch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

                           if((location_touch%2)!=0)
                            {
                                location_touch=0;
                                Toast.makeText(GoogleMapShowActivity.this, "VALUE 2..."+location_touch+"gp is "+p+",,"+p1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                mapView.getOverlays().add(new MarkerOverlay(p,pa));
                                mapView.invalidate();

                            }
                           else //if((location_touch==0 ))
                            {
                              pa=p;
                                Toast.makeText(GoogleMapShowActivity.this, "VALUE 1.."+location_touch+",,,"+p1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                location_touch++;


                            }
```